# Saving contents of multiple text boxes and possibly combo boxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, io, controls

I'm working on a basic application that lets you track experience earned across up to 3 skills. The names of the skills are in a combo box (not sure if the best) and the beginning and ending values are in text boxes.

I want to add a save button that saves the ending values and selected skills, when pressing the load button it would populate the combo boxes with saved skills and input the old ending values into the new beginning ones.

I've been working on this all day, searching for a long time I've come up with similar solutions but nothing seems to work right. I'm still a bit of a beginner so some of the solutions I don't understand. Also, this has to work for VBNet.

The closest solution I've come across is:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\Data.txt", String.Join("|", new String({TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text}))
```

I'd like the file to stay with the project in the main directory though. Would this work for combo boxes as well, and how to load the values back in?

I'm still a newbie to VB, hope this question makes sense.

Comment: That code doesn't look right.  It should be `File.WriteAllText("C:\Data.txt", String.Join("|", New String() {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text}))`.  Note the slightly different locations of parentheses.  Even simpler, it could be `File.WriteAllText("C:\Data.txt", String.Join("|", {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text}))` so there's no confusion.

Comment: This isn't really stuff to ask us.  You need to research first.  There's plenty of information out there about reading text files and manipulating `Strings`.  You ask here about the stuff you can't find for yourself.  As for whether it will work for `ComboBoxes`, just test it for yourself.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not clear from your question: I changed the tag to `winforms`, but that's my assumption only. Please review. If this is WPF, then you should use data bindings instead. Also, you are lumping a few questions together, which is not the best way to ask, really: specific questions are preferred on SO (it takes more time, but gets you better rep in the end!).

Answer (score 0):

If I get your idea right, please find some functions below if they can help:

- One can read (or write) text:

  This one can populate the needed string to 3 textboxes `txtSkill1`, `txtSkill2`, `txtSkill3`

  ```
  Sub ReadTextFile()
    Dim lineCount As Integer = 0
    Dim rndInstance As New Random
    Dim idx As Integer = 0
    Dim selectedLine As String = ""

    Dim txt As String = "Skills.txt"
    If Not File.Exists(txt) Then
        File.Create(txt).Dispose()

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(txt, True)
        ' 2 sample text lines:
        objWriter.WriteLine("Negotiating - Interpersonal - Working independently")
        objWriter.WriteLine("Goal oriented - Leadership - Teamwork")
        objWriter.Close()
    End If

    lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(txt).Length
    idx = rndInstance.Next(1, lineCount + 1) ' the index can be random if you want, or run from (1 to lineCount)
    selectedLine = ReadLineWithNumberFrom(txt, idx)

    Dim pattern As String = "-" ' split on hyphens
    Dim subStrings() As String = Regex.Split(selectedLine, pattern)
    txtSkill1.Text = subStrings(0)
    txtSkill2.Text = subStrings(1)
    txtSkill3.Text = subStrings(2)
  End Sub
  ```
- One can read a string from a specific line number:

  ```
  Function ReadLineWithNumberFrom(filePath As String, ByVal lineNumber As Integer) As String
    Using file As New StreamReader(filePath)
      ' Skip all preceding lines: 
      For i As Integer = 1 To lineNumber - 1
          If file.ReadLine() Is Nothing Then
              Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber")
          End If
      Next
      ' Attempt to read the line you're interested in:
      Dim line As String = file.ReadLine()
      If line Is Nothing Then
          Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber")
      End If
      ' Succeeded!
      Return line
    End Using
  End Function
  ```

Now with the functions allow you to write to any text file, to read from any text file, from any line number, with specific separator (here is the hyphen -- char), you can `Save` and `Load` any string you need.